# mount failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

when I try this command sudo mount -o ro,loop win7ultimate.iso /mnt/win7 I gave mount: /mnt/win7: mount failed: Operation not permitted.

I tried to use these commands in wsl: https://github.com/OpenSecureCo/Demos/blob/main/Cuckoo%20Install

How can solve this error?

I tried to close and open wsl but it does not work.

Comment: Is it possible that you made a mistake in executing one of the commands from the script? 
 Have you confirmed the permissions of the mountpoint?